# Django - Paginating in Template using multiple GET parameters

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using a Django Paginator and I want to have multiple available get parameters, such as:
page=1
sort_by=price

However, in my template tags I have:

```
Showing items sorted by {{ SORT_PARAM }}.
Showing {{ ITEMS_PER_PAGE }} items per page.

{% if has_prev %}
<a href="?page={{ prev_page }}">Previous</a> |
{% endif %}
```

However, this does not preserve the other GET variables. What I mean is, if I'm viewing

```
page/?page=1&sort_by=price
```

and I click the link in the template fragment above, I will go to

```
page=2
```

instead of

```
page=2&sort_by=price
```

What I mean is, the a href does not preserve the other GET parameters.

One solution is I could type all the possible GET parameters in the a href, such as

```
<a href="?page={{ prev_page }}&items_per_page={{ ITEMS_PER_PAGE }}&sort_param={{ SORT_PARAM }}">Previous</a>
```

but this will become less scalable the more arguments I want to add to my browsing. I'm guessing there should be an automated way to obtain all GET parameters, and then pass those and one more?

Comment: try to create special template_tag: ie. {% pager_url page=page_no items_per_page=ITEMS_PER_PAGE sort_param=SORT_PARAM %} (btw. if you take some params (ie. ITEMS_PER_PAGE) from settings, you don't need to pass it explicitly)

Comment: Thanks. That might be worth a shot

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30552369/5823489) was the one for me. In Django2 you can use it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 'parameter-string'. Let's supose that in your code you have:

```
my_view( request, page, options):
    sort_choices = {P:'price',N:'name', ...}
    n_item_choices = {'S':5, 'L':50, 'XL':100)
    ascending_descending_choices = {'A':'', 'D':'-'}
    ...
```

then you can concatenat options as:

```
options='P-S-D'  #order by price, 5 items per page, descending order
```

encode opions as:

```
<a href="?page={{ prev_page }}&options={{ options }}">Previous</a>
```

then, in urls.py capture options and in view:

```
my_view( request, page, options):
   ... #choides ....
   try:
      optionsArray = options.split('-')
      sort_by = sort_choices[ optionsArray[0]  ]
      n_ites_page = n_item_choices[ optionsArray[1]  ]
      asc_or_desc = ascending_descending_choices[ optionsArray[2]  ]
      ...
   except:
      somebody is playing ....
```

with this method you are free to add more paginations options without modify urls.py, all you need is to append options at the end of string options .  This has advantages but also some dangers: I hope you can identify risks.

Answer (score 5):

This one http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1592/ looks cleaner

Comment: `has_key` was removed in Python 3. In this case, you have to change this line `if queries_without_page.has_key('page'):` to `if "page" in queries_without_page:`

Answer (score 0):

With Django's Pagination - preserving the GET params is simple.

First copy the GET params to a variable (in view):

```
GET_params = request.GET.copy()
```

and send it to the template in via context dictionary:

```
return render_to_response(template,
                        {'request': request, 'contact': contact, 'GET_params':GET_params}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Second thing you need to do is use it specify it in the url calls (href) in the template - an example (extending the basic pagination html to handle extra param condition):

```
{% if contacts.has_next %}
    {% if GET_params %}
        <a href="?{{GET_params.urlencode}}&amp;page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047622/how-to-paginate-django-with-other-get-variables/#36053471) - Posted same answer.