# Pagination in django - the original query string gets lost

Tags: python, django

I use the code from the documentation to paginate the data:

```
try:
    data = paginator.page(request.GET.get('page'))
except PageNotAnInteger:
    page = 1
    data = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

And a page:

```
<div class="pagination">
      <span class="step-links">
          {% if data.has_previous %}
              <a href="?page={{ data.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
          {% endif %}

          <span class="current">
              <b>Page</b> {{ data.number }} of {{ data.paginator.num_pages }}
          </span>

          {% if data.has_next %}
              <a href="?page={{ data.next_page_number }}">next</a>
          {% endif %}

      </span>
    </div>
```

But there's a bug here: when the url contains a query string and one clicks on the Pager, the original query string gets lost. For example:

```
example.com?var1=33&var2=44
```

and then when one clicks on "page2", the url becomes

```
example.com?page=2  # var1=33&var2=44 is lost
```

instead of:

```
example.com?var1=33&var2=44&page=2
```

I haven't found neither the standard, nor easy way to fix it. How can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

of course, the names of the parameters, their values and whether they exist or not is not known.

Comment: I used one of the two simple solutions mentioned [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html). Also, its important to note that a javascript solution (as suggested in a few SO posts) may work here but may affect the SEO since page links wont be real URLs in that case

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access parameters from your request directly in your template if you activate `django.core.context_processors.request` in your settings. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request

Then you can access parameters in your template directly. In your case you'll need to filter `page` parameter. You could do something like this:

```
href="?page={{ data.next_page_number }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```

Comment: The `for loop` in this causes `%20` whitespace encoding issues.

Answer (score 19):

Another possible solution can be to construct parameters list in your view. Pros: you can use clean and expressive methods on `QueryDict`.

It will be look like this:

```
get_copy = request.GET.copy()
parameters = get_copy.pop('page', True) and get_copy.urlencode()
context['parameters'] = parameters
```

That's it! Now you can use your `context` variable in template:

```
 href="?page={{ paginator.next_page_number }}&{{ parameters }}"
```

See, code looks clean and nicely.

*note: assumes, that your context contained in `context` dict and your paginator in `paginator` variable*

Comment: My preferred solution after googling on this topic. Very neat!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to include those variables in your template:

```
<a href="?var1={{var1}}&var2={{var2}}&page={{ data.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

Just add `var1` and `var2` to your `context`.

That's if the query string variables are originated from your backend. If they're coming from the front-end/external, you could use something like [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/2532070) in your template and either edit the template vars directly or pass the values to your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to YPCrumble's answer, the following snippet works for me. But the template files could get pretty crowded when there are multiple parameters.

```html
<a href="?p={{ page }}{% if search %}&search={{ search }}{% endif %}">{{ page }}</a>
```

Note that you must know the parameter names when apply this solution, so it may not fully satisfy your need.