# Overriding django admin pagination along with url parameters

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to implement custom pagination for my admin panel.

My url looks like the following:
`http://localhost:8000/admin/items/?group_id=20`

On this URL I do some work to filter the results using the parameter `group_id` (by overriding `get_changelist` method).

The page results are corrects, the problem is my pagination ending up like this `http://localhost:8000/admin/items/?p=1` whereas I would like the URL to be `http://localhost:8000/admin/items/?group_id=20&p=1` and keep the parameter.

Basically I want the same result as [How to paginate Django with other get variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047622/how-to-paginate-django-with-other-get-variables) but using Django admin.

How can I keep the parameter along with the pagination?

I've tried overriding pagination.html file but without any success.

Thank you.

**Edit**

I've tried overriding pagination.html but `request.GET.items` is still empty (even if my settings file is well configured)

```
{% load admin_list %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load content_extras %}
<p class="paginator">
{% if pagination_required %}
    {% for i in page_range %}
        <a href="?p={{ i }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'p' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">{{ i }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{{ cl.result_count }} {% if cl.result_count == 1 %}{{ cl.opts.verbose_name }}{% else %}{{ cl.opts.verbose_name_plural }}{% endif %}
{% if show_all_url %}<a href="{{ show_all_url }}" class="showall">{% trans 'Show all' %}</a>{% endif %}
{% if cl.formset and cl.result_count %}<input type="submit" name="_save" class="default" value="{% trans 'Save' %}">{% endif %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FOUND A SOLUTION:**

1/ Override `changelist_view` on `admin.py` and pass the extra data

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=""):
    response = super(ItemAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    group_id = request.GET.get('group_id', None)

    if group_id:
        extra_context = {
            'group_id': group_id,
        }
        response.context_data.update(extra_context)

    return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/changelist.html", response.context_data)
```

2/ Create `changelist.html` file based on django admin [template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) (copy/paste)

Add `{% load content_extras %}` at the top of the file (line 3)

Change line `{% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}` with `{% block pagination %}{% custom_pagination cl %}{% endblock %}`

3/ Create `content_extras.py` under `templatetags` folder and write `custom_pagination` function

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags import admin_list

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('admin/pagination.html', takes_context=True)
def custom_pagination(context, cl):
    pagination = admin_list.pagination(cl)
    if 'group_id' in context:
        params = (('group_id', context['group_id']),)
        pagination['params'] = params
    return pagination
```

4/ Create `pagination.html` (same location as `changelist.html`)

```
{% load admin_list %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load content_extras %}
<p class="paginator">
{% if pagination_required %}
    {% for i in page_range %}
        <a href="?p={{ i }}{% for key, value in params %}{% if key != 'p' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">{{ i }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{{ cl.result_count }} {% if cl.result_count == 1 %}{{ cl.opts.verbose_name }}{% else %}{{ cl.opts.verbose_name_plural }}{% endif %}
{% if show_all_url %}<a href="{{ show_all_url }}" class="showall">{% trans 'Show all' %}</a>{% endif %}
{% if cl.formset and cl.result_count %}<input type="submit" name="_save" class="default" value="{% trans 'Save' %}">{% endif %}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you activated [`django.template.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) in your settings, you can access parameters from your request directly from your template.

And then you can access the parameters in your templates directly. Something like:

```html
href="?page={{ data.next_page_number }}{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}{% if key != 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```

[Research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30552369) (`context_processors.request` was moved from `django.core` to `django.templates` some time ago)

Comment: I've tried your solution (edit above) but still receiving empty array for `request.GET.items`

Answer (score 0):

Another relatively clean solution that only involves Python code could be following:

1. Override the `get_query_string` method by providing your custom `ChangeList` class.

   ```
    from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList 

    class MyCustomChangeList(ChangeList):
        def get_query_string(self, new_params=None, remove=None):
           new_params = new_params or {}
           # inject custom query params to pagination links
           new_params.update(self.model_admin.custom_query_params)
           return super().get_query_string(new_params, remove)
   ```
2. Use your custom `ChangeList` class in admin:

   ```
     class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       custom_query_params = {}

       def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
           return MyCustomChangeList

       def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
           self.custom_query_params = {}
           # set query param aside for access later 
           self.custom_query_params['group_id'] = request.GET.get('group_id')

           return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
   ```

Now your custom query params will be part of the pagination urls along with page parameter `?p=2&group_id=xx`.