# Django pagination -- maintaining filter and order by

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I've a small Django project [basic-pagination](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/basic-pagination/tree/master). There is one model, one form and two views (list view, form view). User submits data in the form view, then the data is displayed in the list view. Pagination is enabled to only display 5 posts at a time.

What I've implemented is a form with a GET response to get the data I want to display (e.g. name, date). See code below

```
class FormListView(ListView):
    model = models.ToDoList
    paginate_by = 5  # if pagination is desired
    template_name = 'pagination/listview.html'
    context_object_name = 'forms'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Form List View'
        context['filter_form'] = forms.FilterListView(self.request.GET)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = models.ToDoList.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        name = self.request.GET.get('name')
        if name:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)
        order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by')
        if order_by:
            queryset = queryset.order_by(order_by)
        print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

The **problem** is that the class based view [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) calls the method [`get_queryset`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L21) if you are moving from page `1` to page `2` and thus losing the filtered queryset I wanted.

How can I maintain the filtering throughout the pagination process?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the view: it is in your template that you write URLs that do not use the other parameters from the query, but only the `page` parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you have a suggested fix for that?

Comment: Have you seen this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386191/django-paginating-in-template-using-multiple-get-parameters) which looks like it is dealing with a related topic?

Comment: @Chris I think I found a fix. I changed the `href` for each link. For example, `href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"` --> `href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ request.GET.urlencode }}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem pointed out, the problem is not with the view, but rather with the URLs in the template (templates/pagination/listview.html). Previously, the **next** button had `href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"` which meant that `request.GET` would only contain the page number for pagination and not the other filter and order by criteria.

The solution was then to append `request.GET.urlencode` to `href` like

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">Next</a>
```

However, this is not a total fix because simply appending `request.GET` also appends the page number you're currently at. Simply put, if you jump from page 1 to 2 to 3, you will end up with a URL that looks like

```
http://localhost:8000/listview/?page=1&page=2&page=3...
```

The `request.GET` is a QueryDict like `<QueryDict: {'page': ['1'], ...}>`. A solution to this was to simply pop the `page` parameter, however, because `request.GET` is immutable you first have to make a copy of it. Essentially, I added the following lines to [`get_context_data`](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/basic-pagination/blob/master/pagination/views.py#L28) method in the ListVew

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = 'Form List View'
    context['filter_form'] = forms.FilterListView(self.request.GET)
    get_copy = self.request.GET.copy()
    if get_copy.get('page'):
        get_copy.pop('page')
    context['get_copy'] = get_copy
    return context
```

And in the template I called the `get_copy` object like `href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ get_copy.urlencode }}"`

For the entire template example follow [templates/pagination/listview.html](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/basic-pagination/blob/master/pagination/templates/pagination/listview.html#L60)

Not the most elegant solution, but I feel it's simple enough for most people to utilize.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem and I solved it with the link below.

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/10/18/filtering-and-pagination-django/

Comment: Could you add context as to what/how you solved the issue? Linking to an external site doesn't suffice as an answer