# Django Pagination with other variables in the GET request in a Function Based View

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

I've tried to implement the following solution from here:
[How to paginate Django with other get variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047622/how-to-paginate-django-with-other-get-variables)

I added this to my **views.py**

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def url_replace(request, field, value):

    dict_ = request.GET.copy()

    dict_[field] = value

    return dict_.urlencode()

def teacher_list(request, **kwargs):
    paginator = Paginator(results, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        results = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

template.html

```
{% if teacher_list.has_next %}
<li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'page' teacher_list.next_page_number %}">Next</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

> However, this gives me: Invalid block tag on line 155: 'url_replace',
>   expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load
>   this tag?

I also tried loading:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(context, **kwargs):
    query = context['request'].GET.dict()
    query.update(kwargs)
    return urlencode(query)
```

without success. I also tried:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(request, **kwargs):
    query = request.GET.dict()
    query.update(kwargs)
    return urlencode(query)
```

None of these seem to work.

Comment: did you load your tags by added load to the template  `{% load YourTagModuleName %}`?

Comment: Do you mean {% load 'simple_tag' %} in the template.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django could not to load your tag

by docs [custom-template-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)

you need add `templatetags` (change `your_app` and  `your_tags` on your valid values):

```
your_app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        your_tags.py
```

in the template load your tags

```
{% load your_tags %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. I hope there are no security implications with such way of using GET requests. Also, I was wondering if you offer consulting services?

Comment: glad to help you! i'm not sure for security, any way i think it better to use some mapping of available get params. about consulting: in my mind SO more better solution)

Comment: Yes, SO is great, but there are some bits to the projects that are beyond the scope that I can learn anytime soon and I'm concerned about my code optimisation. I would also like to launch the projects and I would like to have someone senior to look and improve my code. If you work as a freelancer, I would gladly pay for your services.

Comment: sorry for long time of the answer, but now i'm working on hard project, and SO it is place where i can to relax a little.

Comment: Oh, no problem :)