# changeing ListView get_queryset? pagination in django

Tags: python, django, listview, search, paginator

Good day everyone.
I am having some trouble with the paginator in django.
I have in my db all the customers info, so what I want to do is to display that info, but I made a search function in which you clic a letter button, for example you clic  A  and it will filter all the customers that their last name starts with the letter A, if you clic B , it will filter all customers with their last name start with B, and so on. This works correctly, the problem is that I also want to display 10 customers per page, so if I have 20 customers that their last name starts with the letter A, what you will see, will be 10 customers and a bar that says ( <<< page 1 page 2 >>> ) or something like that, and that should be solved with the paginator, I added it, but its not working.
I think the problem is that maybe my get function is rewriting the get_query function from ListView perhaps? I tryed different things but I'm not sure.
Here is my code in views:

```
class ExpedientView(ListView):
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(products__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
    template_name = 'dashboard-admin/portfoliorecords.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get(self,request):
        if request.GET['letter'] == '':
            context_object_name = 'portfolios'
            queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(products__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
            context = queryset
        else:
            letter = request.GET['letter']
            context_object_name = 'portfolios'
            queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(products__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name').filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
            context = queryset
        return render(request, 'dashboard-admin/portfoliorecords.html', {'portfolios': context})
```

the get(self,request) function, works perfectly, however the first part where the paginated_by is not working.

Before I added the get function, and just filtering all the customers, the paginator worked fine, so in the template, the code works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the `def get_queryset(self)` method not the `def get(self, request)` method

Remove the `def get(self, request)` method and the below code.

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(products__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
    letter = request.GET.get('letter', None)
    if letter:
        queryset.filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is dynamically change the queryset then instead of overriding `get` (Which calls the appropriate functions in the view, which will perform all pagination tasks, etc.) you should be overriding `get_queryset`:

```
class ExpedientView(ListView):
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(products__isnull=True)
    template_name = 'dashboard-admin/portfoliorecords.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = 'owner__last_name' # Put the ordering here instead of specifying it in the queryset

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        letter = self.request.GET.get('letter')
        if letter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
        return queryset
```

Comment: I see, instead of changing the get function from the original ListView class, it was easier putting everything in the get_queryset.

Comment: This worked well. However another problem appeared once this worked lol.
What I'm doing on the template, is sending the info by GET method, like this:
<form action="expediente" method="GET">
<button type="submit" name="letter" value="A">A</button>
</form>

However, the paginator works, but when you change the page, lets say change to page 2, the url instead of being mypage.com/expediente?letter=A, it changes to mypage.com/expediente?page=2  and displays all the customers of the second page (doesn't take the filter due to there is no variable letter=A )

Comment: @add that is a different question, although easily solved, infact you will find some duplicates too on SO for example see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047622/how-to-paginate-django-with-other-get-variables